# react native FlatList not rerendering when data prop changes

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I have a `FlatList` component that uses Redux (indirectly) as the source for the `data` prop.  See below

```
 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   rdx_activeUsers: state.profile.activeUsers,
 });
        
 convertRdxActiveUsersObjectToUsableArray = () => {
   let activeUsersArray = [];
   Object.values(this.props.rdx_activeUsers).forEach(userObj => {
       activeUsersArray.push(userObj);
   });
   return activeUsersArray;
 };
 //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 render() {
    let usableArray4FlatList = this.convertRdxActiveUsersObjectToUsableArray();
    
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={usableArray4FlatList}
```

Whenever an active user is added or removed in Firebase DB, I have listeners that increase or reduce the size of the Redux object `rdx_activeUsers`.......the goal is that this change in Redux should trigger the `render()` function (due to Redux being used in the  `convertRdxActiveUsersToUsableArray` function....which is present in the `render()` function).

I can see via debugging tool that Redux `rdx_activeUsers` object **is updating correctly whenever I add or remove a user**....*however* the FlatList only rerenders dynamically when I **add** a user (i.e. the Redux object `rdx_activeUsers` increases in size)...but not when I **remove** one (i.e the Redux object `rdx_activeUsers` decreases in size).

I also tried adding prop `extraData={this.props.rdx_activeUsers}` ...but this didnt make any difference

**UPDATE AS OF 12/31**
Below are my reducers......
`case ACTIVE_USER_CHILD_ADDED` is successfully updating Redux **AND** triggering the rerender
`case ACTIVE_USER_CHILD_REMOVED` is successfully updating Redux **BUT NOT** triggering the rerender....looks like thats where the issue is

```
case ACTIVE_USER_CHILD_ADDED:
  const key2Add = action.payload.userId;
  const val2Add = action.payload;

  return { ...state, activeUsers: { ...state.activeUsers, [key2Add]: val2Add } };


case ACTIVE_USER_CHILD_CHANGED:
  const key2Updel = action.payload.userId;
  const val2Updel = action.payload;

   if (val2Updel.active) {
        return { ...state, activeUsers: { ...state.activeUsers,[key2Updel]: val2Updel } };
    }
  
  if (state.activeUsers) {
    const updatedstate = state;
    delete updatedstate.activeUsers[key2Updel];
    return {...updatedstate};
  }
  //else
  return state;

case ACTIVE_USER_CHILD_REMOVED:
  const key2Del = action.payload.userId;
  const oldState = state;
  delete oldState.activeMsgUsers[key2Del];
  return {...oldState};
```

Below shows my action creators

```
export const _actActiveUserChildAdded = userObj => {
  return {
    type: ACTIVE_USER_CHILD_ADDED,
    payload: userObj,
  };
};

export const _actActiveUserChildChanged = userObj => {
  return {
    type: ACTIVE_USER_CHILD_CHANGED,
    payload: userObj,
  };
};

export const _actActiveUserChildRemoved = userObj => {
  return {
    type: ACTIVE_USER_CHILD_REMOVED,
    payload: userObj,
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you provide a minified code of how you're dispatching remove item action and corresponding reducer? Make sure that you do not accidentally mutate the `activeUsers` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change case `ACTIVE_USER_CHILD_REMOVED` like following it should work, you are modifying the object which was mutating the state object instead of returning a new object.

```
case ACTIVE_USER_CHILD_REMOVED:
  const key2Del = action.payload.userId;
  const {activeUsers:{[key2Del]:_,...restActiveUsers}} = state;
  return {...state,activeUsers:{...restActiveUsers}};
```

Comment: This works - thank you.
Are you able to explain in a little more detail what the line of code below is doing?
const {activeUsers:{[key2Del]:_,...restActiveUsers}} = state;  
Im particularly interested in the underscore.....Ive never seen that used before

Comment: I actually found an article that explains what you did - thanks again
https://dmitripavlutin.com/remove-object-property-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code does not trigger a rerender

```
case ACTIVE_USER_CHILD_REMOVED:
  const key2Del = action.payload.userId;
  const oldState = state;
  delete oldState.activeMsgUsers[key2Del];
  return {...oldState};
```

By returning `{...oldState}` all the references inside `this.state` stay the same, and no update is triggered

### fast solution

Put `return {...oldState, activeMsgUsers: {...activeMsgUsers}}` instead

### better solution

Don't use `delete`, use `Array.filter` instead to create a new object reference

### best solution

Refactor your conponent to hooks and make `activeMsgUsers` a standalone state, if you do it correctly, calling `setActiveMsgUsers` returning the destructured old state you cannot have that problem

Comment: "fast solution" results in error as {...activeMsgUsers} is undefined

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   rdx_activeUsers: state.profile.activeUsers,
 });
        

 //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 render() {
    let activeUsersArray = [];
   Object.values(this.props.rdx_activeUsers).forEach(userObj => {
       activeUsersArray.push(userObj);
   });
    
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={activeUsersArray}
```

Comment: This did not make a difference